# Taking a photo without preview in android

Tags: android, image, photo, capture

I'm learning android studio and I'm currently working on a robotics project in which an Android phone is placed on the robot and used as the processor, therefore I can't reach the phone by hand. The phone needs to do some image processing. And it's not a real-time processing so I need to take a photo (Preferably Bitmap) whenever I want, quickly and **without preview and confirmation**. I've tried some tutorials and they all open the camera app and the user needs to capture and then confirm the photo.
I don't have problem with the processing and I don't need to use openCV etc. I just need help with capturing the photo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own camera, either via the camera APIs (hard) or by using a library (CameraKit-Android, Fotoapparat, etc.), thank you will have control, you can directly save the image without previewing it